# How to add elements into a randomly position of a 2d array/matrix?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, while-loop

Hey I was trying to add elements on random position of a matrix a[3][3];
The problem is that when it remains 2-3 free position on the matrix, the program crashes. Refuses to get out of the while loop.

```
char a[3][3]={{ '.' , '.' , '.' },{ '.' , '.' , '.' },{ '.' , '.' , '.' }};
if(selected!=true&&postpone!=true&&elemctr<8)
    {
        Orow=rand()%3;
        Ocol=rand()%3;
        while(1)
        {
            cout << "in while";
            cout << endl;

        if(a[Orow][Ocol]=='.')
            {
                if(Orow!=Xrow||Ocol!=Xcol)
                {
                    fct();
                    ocalled=true;
                }   
            }

        else
            {
                //-------------------
                for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                {
                    for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
                    {
                        if(a[i][j]=='.')
                        {
                            Orow=i;
                            Ocol=j;
                            found=true;
                            break;
                        }
                        if(found==true)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    if(found==true)
                    {
                        break;
                    }   
                }
            }
            if(ocalled==true)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

What to do, to avoid being stuck in the while loop, and to complete all the matrix position taken randomly with a certain element?

Comment: A fine debugger target if I ever saw one.

Comment: too many things we don't see, e.g. what is fct(), what are Xrow, Xcol? Also consider adding `srand(time(NULL));` to randomize the seed of your rand() function or it will return the same sequence of numbers each time. Also, I think your problem is that you're calling rand() only twice out of while loop, so you're not actually filling your matrix at random positions and that's why you never leave loop.

Answer (score 1):

at first glance I think you are not setting back 0row and 0col. They are 3 in the end and the while loop will not terminate.

Cheers